# Wubi's Ubuntu files

Tags: windows, wubi, files, windows-8

Can I access to Wubi's files from Windows? I saved a few files on my Ubuntu desktop and I'd like to access them even when I'm running Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) which allows you to read ext2 and 3 partitions in Windows. This program works in every version of Windows.
There is some valuable information in the [Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20can%20I%20access%20the%20Wubi%20files%20from%20Windows?)

Comment: Does it support `ext4`? Some wubi installs are `ext4` depending on how you install, in which case `ext2read` works: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/

Comment: Based on their website I am going to say that it only supports ext2 & 3 but it doesn't hurt to try. If that doesn't work you could always set up dropbox or Ubuntu one to sync files.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what your file system is. You can do this as follows:

```
bcbc@16:14:50:~$ mount | grep ' / '
/dev/loop0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

If your file system shows up as `ext4` then you can use [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/), but this is read-only access. If it's `ext3` then [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/) will still work, and others such as [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) will likely work. The website for [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) seems to indicate that it's read only access too.

I've used [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/) and it's known to work with Wubi when you have an `ext4` file system.

Alternatively, you should consider storing shared data on an `NTFS` partition. This is much easier for sharing with Windows and allows read/write access from both Operating Systems. In addition, if the data is important then it's safer to install them directly to the `/host` or another mounted partition, rather than storing them on a [loop device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) (the Wubi virtual disk) that is a single file, and when corrupted can be lost (along with all data within it).

PS a bit of background... Wubi installs are supposed to be `ext4` only, but when Ubuntu 11.10 came out, Wubi added a new *disk image* install option (when `wubi.exe` is used to install Ubuntu only, and with no ISO present), and these disk images were supposed to be `ext4`, but they found out later they were `ext3`. The idea is that they'll switch back to `ext4` when [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/859552) is fixed; it looks like the plan is to do this for release 13.10.

But any Wubi installs from USB/DVD or with the ISO, including Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu etc. all use `ext4`.